# HOW TO CLICK LINK IN PAGE OF REACT-PDF

Tags: reactjs, pdf

**Description:**
I've checked similar issues, but none of the provided solutions seem to work in this case. My assumption is that this has something to do with pdf document itself, appreciate if anyone could take a look.

**Steps to reproduce**
Here is the sandbox with the example
https://codesandbox.io/embed/gallant-thunder-x3o7v7?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

**Expected behavior**
Links are clickable. Please see the online demo https://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-pdf/

**Actual behavior**
Links are not clickable

Interesting fact, that google viewer does not open the links either (pages 4, 5), but if you download the document, links are working. I'm using default previewer on MacOS

**Environment**
React-PDF version: 5.7.2, same behaviour on 4.1.0
React version: 18.0.0, same on 16.4.0

**Also, I used iframe and embed, and really it make link clickable but its not display pdf on safari IOS**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using a "virtual PDF reader" (GoogleDocs/Mozilla PDF.js) which produces images and searchable text as separate layers, the link is there but it is the highlighted yellow zone not the blue underline text. also due to browser security I have to right click to open at my choice in new tab or new window (my choice would be save link as PDF for offline viewing).

[image]

In a true PDF viewer like Chrome embedded PDF Plugin or the users iFrame / offline viewer, the links would work perfectly. Again whichever way the user decides.